How to use sed to locate a Pattern, and create two capture groups from it
I have some scripts with code like:
AND EQUAL_NULL(b.DATE_FIELD, a.DATE_FIELD)

That I want to replace dynamically since b.DATE_FIELD and a.DATE_FIELD can have different fields.
I believe I need to capture each field within the parens as their own capture groups and write them to their new equivalents. Basically, I am thinking whatever is between ( and , would be group 1 and what is between , and ) would be group 2. then I can write them to the new substituted pattern shown below.
Desired End Result:
AND COALESCE(b.DATE_FIELD, 'NA') = COALESCE(a.DATE_FIELD, 'NA')
My attempt:
 echo "AND EQUAL_NULL(b.DATE_LOCAL, a.DATE_LOCAL)" | sed -n "s/AND EQUAL_NULL(\([^,]*\)\([^)]*\).*/COALESCE(\1\, \'NA\'\) = COALESCE(\2\, \'NA\'\)/p"

returns most of what I want:
COALESCE(b.DATE_LOCAL, 'NA') = COALESCE(, a.DATE_LOCAL, 'NA')
I'm not quite sure how to get b.DATE_FIELD as Group \1 and a.DATE_FIELD AS Group \2
Updated Code which is closer to solution but still missing a piece
Tested on Linux with GNU Sed 4.9 using zsh

There's no need to escape comma, single quote, or parentheses in the replacement string.

@Barmar Thanks for the tip! I assume escapes are just used for pattern matching?

The obvious problem is that your regexp puts everything after b.DATE_FIELD in group 2. You need to skip over the comma.

They're used to prevent interpretation of special characters. In the replacement string, the only special characters are \ , / and &, nothing else needs to be escaped.

@Barmar. I see skip over the comma idea. Is there a way to skip over the comma by itself , or if it has a trailing space , ? Basically handling both spellings

Use , * to match a command with any number of spaces after it.

I tested this on MacOS zsh:
echo "AND EQUAL_NULL(b.DATE_LOCAL, a.DATE_LOCAL)" |
sed -n "s/AND EQUAL_NULL(\([^,]*\), \([^)]*\))/COALESCE(\1, 'NA') = COALESCE(\2, 'NA')/p" 

Output:
COALESCE(b.DATE_LOCAL, 'NA') = COALESCE(a.DATE_LOCAL, 'NA')

I think you almost had the solution yourself.

Don't just post code. Explain what the OP did wrong and how you fixed it. Put this explanation in the answer, not a comment.

@Bill Karwin  Any particular reason for the double escaping \\?

I am using zsh as well and non double escapes seems to work? e.g. echo "AND EQUAL_NULL(b.DATE_LOCAL, a.DATE_LOCAL)" | sed -n -e "s/AND EQUAL_NULL(\([^,]*\), \([^)]*\))/COALESCE(\1, 'NA') = COALESCE(\2, 'NA')/p"

Okay fair enough. I tested too without the double backslashes and you're right, it works. I will edit my answer.
